# How to use function implemented in asm from *.cpp file, in VisualDsp++ 5, for Blackfin BF537?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, dct

I have this project explained in "Wiley-Embedded Signal Processing with the Micro Signal Architecture.2007" - **2D DCT/IDCT (image compression)** implemented, and i want to combine (move these files to..) with another personal project with image processing (which have only *.cpp files) in **Visual Dsp** for **Blackfin BF 537**. (first in **Simulator**, and after that on the board BF537..)

The implemented project 2D DCT/IDCT has *.**c** and *.**asm** files and it **works** verry well. At some point, for some calculations, from C file is using a function declared (and implemented) in asm file.

I noticed that if i move these *.c files in my project (which contain only *.cpp files), i get lots of errors and some like this one:

```
"`[Error li1021] The following symbols referenced in processor 'p0' could not be resolved:
   'something [_something]' referenced from '.\Debug\project name.doj'"
```

So, i think i need to have just *.cpp files in my project (not combination off *.cpp and *.c).

In the **2D DCT/IDCT** project, the problem appear when i'm **changing** all those *.**c** files to *.**cpp** files. When i'm trying to build, i get this linking error:

```
"[Error li1021]  The following symbols referenced in processor 'p0' could not be resolved:
   '_r8x8dct(short *, short *, short *) [__r8x8dct__FPsN21]' referenced from '.\Debug\Start_DCT2.doj'
   '_r8x8invdct_ieee(short *, short *, short *) [__r8x8invdct_ieee__FPsN21]' referenced from '.\Debug\Start_DCT2.doj'"
```

In *.**cpp** file this is how i'm calling the function implemented in asm:

```
     _r8x8dct(in,coeff,temp);
```

In the same *.**cpp** file i include a header file where i declared the function:

```
     void _r8x8dct(fract16 *in, fract16 *coeff, fract16 *temp);
```

And here is part of the *.**asm** file which contain the function:

```
     .section    L1_code;
     .global     __r8x8dct;
     .align      8;
     __r8x8dct:
     .....................................
     __r8x8dct.end:
```

Analog with function `$_r8x8invdct_ieee()`

*please excuse me for my english writing errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call C functions from C++ you need to qualify the C function prototypes with `extern "C"`, e.g.

```
extern "C" void _r8x8dct(fract16 *in, fract16 *coeff, fract16 *temp);
```

or if you have more than one C function you can group the prototypes together like this:

```
extern "C" {

    void _r8x8dct(fract16 *in, fract16 *coeff, fract16 *temp);

    // ... other C function prototypes ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, i grouped the protoypes, and worked! I remember trying something similar yesterday, but with no success... Thanks a lot!!